# Check 2 sets for inclusion in Scala

Tags: scala, set, inclusion

```
abstract class FinSet[T] protected () {
  // given a set other, it returns true iff every element of this is an element of other
  def <=(other:FinSet[T]): Boolean = 
    // ????
```

That is what I am given so far. I am somewhat confused on how to implement this method. Would I be calling the method like so:

```
Set(1,2,3).<=(Set(3,2,1)) which should return true
```

I was wondering if this would work, but it seems too simple:

```
def <=(other:FinSet[T]): Boolean = if (this == other) true else false
```

Just looking for some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, even your *simple* function is better to write as `def <=(other:FinSet[T]): Boolean = this == other`. Obviously this would not satisfy the other part of `<=` -- *what if one set is bigger than another*?  e.g. (set with size 4) <= (set with size 5) should yield true as well. How would you check this?

Comment: oh ok I see your point about if a set is smaller than the other. Is case matching a possibility? Also let's say I didn't need to worry about size difference, would that implementation be correct?

Answer (score 2):

& - means intersection, if second set doesn't have elements from first set, the following code would return false.

```
(thisSet & thatSet) == thisSet
```

In details this code computes the intersection between this set and another set and checks if elements in `this` equal to result of the first expression.

[see `&` or `intersect`(more verbose version) method in Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set)

You can also do something like this:

```
thisSet.forall(x => thatSet contains x)
```

or less verbose:

```
thisSet.forall(thatSet contains _)
```

or like this:

```
(thisSet ++ thatSet) == thatSet
```

or maybe like this:

```
(thatSet -- thisSet).size == (thatSet.size - thisSet.size)
```

Comment: When I try to use forall(x +. thatSet contains x) I get this error:
value forall is not a member of FinSet[T]

I understand why I get the error, so how do I get around this.

Comment: maybe try to use approach with deletion of the elements, the later one.

Comment: Which operations does your set support?

Comment: How about `(thatSet -- thisSet).isEmpty`?

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing the requirement: you want to check if, *for all* elements of this set, the other set *contains* the element.

This sounds like the combination of two more primitive functions that you will probably want anyway. So, if you haven't done so already, I would define the methods:

```
def forall(predicate: T => Boolean): Boolean // Checks that predicate holds for all elements

def contains(elem: T): Boolean // Check that elem is an element of the set
```

Then the method `<=` devolves to:

```
def <=(other: FinSet[T]): Boolean = forall(other.contains)
```

Comment: I have a contains method already defined, but I can't make any other methods that weren't given, so I can't make the forall one

Comment: Why not? Is this a homework question? Anyway, you could always define it as an inner function inside `<=`, then call it.